# resolve port on running play app

Tags: scala, playframework

Is it possible to resolve, on which port is running the play app? When I run the play on port 9001 with sbt:

```
> run 9001
```

I want to be able to pick this option somehow in code:

```
Play.current.getCurrentPort() == 9001 // true
```

Is there such a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation for [Configuration](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/ProductionConfiguration) the default port is 9000.

This means that you should be able to do

```
val port = Play.current.configuration.getInt("http.port").getOrElse(9000)
```

But in order to do that you'll have to start the application with

```
> run -Dhttp.port=9001
```

There might be other ways but this is one possible solution.